# Virtual keypad issue on navigating to next form

Tags: codenameone

We are navigating to one form to another form, when virtual key board is opened the half of the previous form is visible while we close the virtual key board and move on to next form its working fine with out issues.

Its specific to android tablets version 4.4. The issue is not exists in IPAd.

So is there any code to hide this virtual key before navigating to second form.

You Can find the screen shot [image]

The two forms : Initial Form is LoginForm and Send Form is after Login Form.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug, I'd like to get some information on how to reproduce this issue specifically.

You can workaround it by calling `stopEditing()` in the code that shows the next form.

Comment: I have used stopEditing() on Form and TextField Componets , it does not resolve my problem. Can I have any other solution for this

Comment: We found one more issue , when we click on the form the virtual keyboard not closing its persists only on android os tablets

Comment: That's intentional, it allows you to scroll between fields and keep editing. Try wrapping your show method for the next form in a Display.callSerially().